# pandas dataframe group by and agg

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ipython

I am new to ipython and I am trying to do something with dataframe grouping . I have a dataframe like below

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(4), "B": ["B1", "B2", "B1", "B2"], "C": ["C1", "C1", np.nan, "C2"]})
df_test

    A   B   C
0   0   B1  C1
1   1   B2  C1
2   2   B1  NaN
3   3   B2  C2
```

I would like to achieve following things:

1) group by B but creating multilevel column instead of grouped to rows with B1 and B2 as index, B1 and B2 are basically count

2) column A and C are agg function applied with something like {'C':['count'],'A':['sum']}

```
    B
  A B1 B2 C
0 6 2  2  3
```

how ? Thanks

Comment: Why C = 3 in the result?

Comment: counting 1+1+1+0(NaN)=3, not count by group B1 or B2,make sense ? my bad, I should put a NaN there, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing separate actions to each column. You can hack this by aggregating A and C and then taking the value counts of B separately and then combine the data back together.

```
ac = df_test.agg({'A':'sum', 'C':'count'}) 
b = df_test['B'].value_counts()
pd.concat([ac, b]).sort_index().to_frame().T
   A  B1  B2  C
0  6   2   2  3
```

Comment: thanks, how do I add one level 'B' on top of B1 and B2 so they are in same 'group' ?

Comment: found it . something like names = ['Level 0', 'Level 1']
cols1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','C', 'B', 'B','C','C'],['A', 'C', 'B1', 'B2','C1','C2']], names = names)
df_grouped.columns=cols1